# Can the original WotC-published SRD RTF files be found anywhere?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, online-resources, ogl

The “Revised (v3.5) System Reference Document” [page on wizards.com](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/srd35) still exists, but all of its links, described as RTF (rich text file) downloads of a given size, all result in 404 page-not-found errors.

Can these files still be accessed from wizards.com? Failing that, is there any legitimate mirror for them elsewhere, that has the files as Wizards of the Coast published them?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Internet Archive has a deliberate Collection of the [original WotC SRD RTF files](https://archive.org/details/dnd35srd) in its library, separately from the web-archiving project of the Wayback Machine.

(Although the Wayback Machine is the most visible thing the Internet Archive does, the Internet Archive’s core project is actually an ongoing effort to collect open and public domain digital content, like the original SRD, into its library.)

Comment: @Erik Similar but not the same thing -- Archive.org's Wayback Machine indexed the SRD page and its downloads, and Archive.org also stored the files themselves as an independent collection.

Comment: As a "legitimate mirror", I think the IA collection is probably a better answer than the Wayback Machine snapshot. Presuming that archive.org was regularly scraping the source site to ensure its content was up to date - it would look like these resources fell off Wizard's site around the start of 2016 (dates of the files shown on the [download page](https://archive.org/download/dnd35srd) are Jaunary 19, 2016).

Answer (score 15):

### Yes, thanks to the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/srd35) (at least for now)

Fortunately it doesn't seem that Wizard's robots.txt policies or anything else have precluded the SRD page and downloads from being archived by the Internet Archive project. I put in the page URL, randomly selected a snapshot from a few years ago et voila - [all the files are available to download](https://web.archive.org/web/20100201014038/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/srd35).

Unfortunately, if WotC does change their site robots.txt or otherwise forbids the archival of site content (or someone who owns wizards.com in the future does), the effect is retroactive and the snapshots of the archived page will go away. The [archive.org collection](https://archive.org/details/dnd35srd) of the 3.5e SRD pointed to by [Carl's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/124165/28402) is probably a safer long-term resource.

<sub>I was pretty surprised to discover I didn't have this saved somewhere in my old documents folders, so I decided to also copy the archive and put all the files up on my [personal webserver](https://carcer.co.uk/35srd/), for posterity's sake.</sub>

Comment: Why do I always forget the Wayback Machine? Anyway, assuming no one can figure out a way to get the files off of wizards.com, I’ll be accepting this in a few days.

Comment: Note: robots.txt has retroactive effect in the Wayback Machine and relies solely on current domain ownership, so if WotC or some future entity that owns the domain *ever* decide to, they can flip the switch and immediately cut off retrieval of all Wayback Machine archives for any given subset of the site. (AFAIK, the Collection does not have a similar automated vulnerability.)

Comment: @TuggyNE good point, I have updated my answer to mention that caveat.